# Google Crawler adding "/" at the end of url

Tags: googlebot, google-crawlers

The problem is occuring when google itself crawling the website. When crawler came to crawl the url, a "/" is added by itself after the orginal url, which leads crawlers to 404. My Website is [Reports and Insights](https://www.reportsandinsights.com/)

I try to figure out any problem in canonical urls or sitemap, but everything seems normal there.